# Webservice with login and password

Tags: moodle, moodle-api

In Moodle, with webservices, you create users/courses, you update personal data, ... .
But everyone, with APIs&tokens and a browser, can do everything. It's dangerous.
Is possible use a login/password with Moodle's webservices?

Answer (score 0):

Token is something generated on moodle side and should be kept a secret. But you may get generated token by username\password and service name if you want, try [this tutorial](https://docs.moodle.org/dev/Creating_a_web_service_client#How_to_get_a_user_token)